# Need custom Pricing for woocommerce shop page products from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get custom pricing from functions.php. For woocommerce shop page i want the output as follows.
I created a custom taxonamy(team), and i am applying a custom price from the backend.

**Eg :**

```
 1. Taxonomy : Team1
   a)  Product Id : 17,  Price =222;    //Original price $45
   b) Product Id :  18,  Price = 444;   // Original price $55

 2. Taxonomy : Team2
    a) Product Id : 17,  Price =999;    //Original price $45
    b) Product Id :  18,  Price = 888;  // Original price $55
```

How can i get the my example output by using the following code? If any changes or modification please let me  know.

**I am using the following code :**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_regular_price', function ($price, $productd ) {
    foreach($_SESSION['my_array'] as $id => $price1) :

            $regular_price = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_regular_price');
            $price = $regular_price[0];


        if(get_the_ID() == $id) :
        return $price1;
        else :

        return $price;

        endif;

    endforeach;

}, 10, 2 );
```

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: You've told us what you want and what you're doing, but not what problem you're having. What's the actual question here?

Comment: I am not getting the example output using this the above code. if any changes in my code. please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the problem either. Do you want to change the price depending on the taxonomy?

Comment: I've had to solve this before for a wholesale ordering site I built involving different prices for some products based off of final packaging and processing needs for different clients ordering. Favoriting for full answer later. Quick info: I did this by adding a new product meta price field, filling it out for each product that required a different price, using Groups plugin, and then making sure the right price displayed in all templates and got added to cart correctly.

Comment: @helgatheviking I just customized some code based on some forums. `add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price', 10, 2);


function change_price($price, $productd){ if($productd->id == 16): return 160; else return $price;}` Its not working for shop page with different products with different pricings.

Comment: @Satya that code gave me parse errors, so of course it won't work. Once corrected it does change the price for me.

Comment: I changed the way of code and the issue was resolved. Even the code is working in the add_to_cart() also. Now i am getting my different custom pricing on different teams(taxonomy terms).

Answer (score 0):

Once I corrected your parse errors, the code from your comment works.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
function change_price($price, $productd){ 
    if($productd->id == 16): 
        $price = 160;   
    endif;

    return $price;
}
```

Modifying that to check for products in a certain taxonomy term, we'll just use `has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post )`. You will need to adjust the term and tax slugs.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
function change_price($price, $productd){ 
    if( has_term( 'team1', 'teams', $productd->id ) ): 
        $price = 160;   
    endif;

    return $price;
}
```

**Update**

Reading your new question, it seems like you are going about this wrong (I could still be misunderstanding you though). If Product 1 is in *both* Team 1 and Team 2, you could change the price on the taxonomy page using `is_taxonomy("team-A")` but all `add_to_cart()` functionality wouldn't know to use the correct price because there will be no way to discern which price it should use based on term (since the product is in both terms).

If you want to display different prices to different groups of Users, then you would need a custom user capability and use that to check when the current user has that cap or not..ex: `current_user_can('team-b')`.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  The code is giving the last product update only for shop page.  Here i assigned pricing for product Id's 14,16,17,etc..  For Product 14=$200, 16=$800, $17=$700,etc.. But, your modification giving only the last product price change.

Comment: I used ur code as `add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
function change_price($price, $productd){ 
    if( has_term( 'A-Team', 'team', $productd->id ) ): 
    
    $wst_team_price = get_post_meta($productd->id, 'tax_32', true);
    
        $price = $wst_team_price;   
    endif;

    return $price;
}`

Comment: @sphanley I might be more clear over here [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668450/woocommerce-multiple-products-with-custom-pricing-from-functions-php)

Comment: Why did you create a new question instead of editing this question? Also, I do not understand what you mean by "the code is giving the last product update only for shop page". And you used my code, but what was the result?

Comment: As per your given solution. In 'team1' having 5 products with different pricing. Applying `returns 160;` to the 5th product directly. I just given 160 for example. It will change depends on product->id and with the teaxonomy term (eg : team1). I said shop page for example. We are getting those taxonomy term products (team1 products). In archive page. Hope i am clear this this time. If i am not clear please let me know. Thanks for considering.