# Woocommerce multiple products with custom pricing from functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I have used the following code to change price from functions.php. It was working for a single product even in cart page also.  How can i use the code for different products with different pricing? Is that possible?

'team' is a taxonomy and 'A-team', 'B-team' are the terms.  I am assigning products to 'A-team' and 'B-team'.

**For example :**

> For 'A-Team' : product_id 14 = $200, 15 = $600, 17 = $800;
>
> For 'B-Team' : product_id 14 = $100, 15 = $300, 17 = $400;
>
> Original Price : product_id 14 = $55, 15 = $44, 17 = $88;
>
> **In taxonomy archive page :**
>
> If 'A-Team' archive products should show
>
> [product_id 14 = $200, 15 = $600, 17 = $800;]
>
> If 'B-Team' archive products should show
>
> [product_id 14 = $100, 15 = $300, 17 = $400;]

**My Code :**

```
function change_price($price, $productd){ 
   if($productd->id == 16): 
      return 160; 
   else: 
      return $price;
   endif;

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price', 10, 2);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need custom Pricing for woocommerce shop page products from functions.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653946/need-custom-pricing-for-woocommerce-shop-page-products-from-functions-php)

Comment: That was not working. I changed the way of code and the issue was resolved. Even the code is working in the add_to_cart() also. Now i am getting my different custom pricing on different teams(taxonomy terms). Anyhow thanks for your support.

Comment: Please post your answer on at least 1 of your threads so that the next person with the same question can find it.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and not as a comment.

Comment: Thanks @helgatheviking. I am new here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed my code as follows. It's working for me. Hope this may helps for some other who have some problem.

```
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', function ($price, $productd ) { 
       if($team_id) :
          return get_post_meta($productd->id, 'tax_'.$team_id , true); 
       else:
          return $price;
       endif;

  }, 10, 2 );`
```

No problems even at 'Add-to-cart' functionality also.

Thanks,
Satya

Comment: I'm not a fan of anonymous functions in WordPress. But I am curious, how is `$team_id` defined? Based on the code you've provided, you should always get the `$price` returned, unaltered, because `$team_id` will never be true.

Comment: i given $team_id for clear understanding purpose. I am getting the value dynamically using sessions.  For example: in taxonomy archive page we have id of a taxonomy. I have given a custom field and saving with 'tax_'.<taxonomy_id> for each product with my custom pricing. Using get_post_meta function i am calling the value here.  It's working for me.

Comment: Ok. I was just pointing out for future visitors that this code (as is) will only ever return the unadjusted price.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Satya, and helgatheviking. I had created a custom field for users in which they set their currency (USD or EURO). And I had created two custom fields for every product: "_price_usd" "_price_euro", each containing the product's US dollar price and the European price in EUROs. Using an anonymous function solved a couple of problems. Now I just have to input the right suffix or prefix depending on the user's currency. Here is my adapted version of your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', function ($price, $productd ) { 
        $logged_in_user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $user_currency = get_user_meta( $logged_in_user_id, 'usd_euro', true );
        $new_price = strtolower("_price_".$user_currency);
        return get_post_meta($productd->id, $new_price, true); 

  }, 10, 2 );
```